# NoMethodError in Users#index: undefined method `name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have a relationship between Users and Accounts:

A user belongs to an account. An account can have many users.

The relationship works, as you can see in the following query:

```
2.1.4 :010 > User.last.account.name
  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL  ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Account Load (2.4ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts"  WHERE "accounts"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
 => "Account A"
```

But if I display an index view of users I get an error when I try to show the account name:

OK

```
<%= user.account_id %>
```

KO

```
<%= user.account.name %>
```

ERROR:

```
NoMethodError in Users#index
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

<tbody>
             <% @users.each do |user| %>
               <tr>
                 <td><a href="/accounts/<%= user.account_id %>"><%= user.account.name %></a></td>
```

Comment: Some of your users have no associated account

Comment: the error suggests that account is nil. can you post the models where you've declared the belongs_to and has_many relationships?

Comment: One of the users has no account, simple like this.

Comment: @Lut - idiomatic way is `user.account && user.account.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being thrown because there would be some `users` who have no associated `account`.

If you are using `Rails 3`:

```
 <%= user.account.name if user.account.present? %>
```

If you are using `Rails 4`:

```
<%= user.account.try(:name) %>
```

Comment: `#try` works from Rails 2.3.2. From Rails 4.0.2 it *also* returns `nil` for unknown methods *on existing objects*.

Answer (score 1):

`name` is being applied to `account`, and it's complaining that `account` is `nil`.

You'll find that for one of the users in `@users`, `user.account_id` works, but returns either `nil` (which will display as blank in the browser), or an ID for which there is no `Account` record.

If users aren't **required** to have an account, you should probably use **`user.account.try(:name)`** instead. (`#try` is like `#send`, but `nil.try` returns `nil`.)

UPDATE: Actually, since the whole table cell is a link to the account, try this instead:

```
<td>
  <% if user.account %>
    <%# user.account definitely exists if you get into this block. %>
    <%= link_to user.account.name, user.account %>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

Comment: Prefer try!  to try (try also returns nil if you do user.account.try(:badassroflcopter) )

Comment: Depends. In this case it should be reasonable to expect that `user.account` either `is_a? Account` or `== nil`, and nothing else; so insisting on the `!` version (in this case) may be just a bit pedantic.

Comment: In the context it is reasonable to assume that, however I'd still want to be protected against the `name` method/column being renamed. Anyway it is an additional difference between try/send

Answer (score -1):

You need to define @users in your controller. I don't see your controller, but I assume something like:

```
def index
 @users = User.all
end
```

The error is telling you that name is returning 'nil'. Does every user have an account.name? I would start by adding <%= user.account.name `rescue nil` %> and see if any account names show up.

Comment: Why is this down voted? The clear answer is that one of the account.name calls is nil, hence it's calling nothing and needs to be rescued.

Comment: if `@users` variable were not assigned, it would be `undefined method each for nil`. It is not `name` that returns nil, it is `user.account` that is nil. Adding exception handlers because there is an exception is not a fix, it is a way to hide the real issue.

Comment: What you just said is exactly what I just said. The requested record is not there, thus unless you want the code to break, there needs to be a way to rescue if one of the user records doesn't have an association.

Comment: You wrote `the error is telling you that name is returning 'nil'`- which is not true. The error is saying that you tried to invoke method `name` on `nil` object which doesn't define that method. `name` doesn't return anything as it is never invoked.

Comment: `The requested record is not there` *... but the rest of the records **are** there.* The problem is not with `@users` as a whole, only with one of them.